# Loading multiple word addins with CefGlue targetting different version of chromium?

Tags: chromium-embedded, cefglue

We have a situation with word addins where we try to load our taskpane and use cefglue implementation to show web page. We use cefglue for the same. We just discovered that one of the vendor addins also loads chromium but an older version. Unfortunately our addin shows a message that it cant load chromium due to hash difference.

Now is it possible that 2 COM addins can load different version of chromium? The vendor change looks unlikely and I could see they don't use cefglue or cefsharp but have their own implementation. Has anyone in this situation before? We are thinking of moving our code base to use same version as theirs but again when they upgrade, we have to upgrade and we will have a window where this fails due to incompatible version. thanks

Comment: See https://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=14400#p31824

Comment: thanks a lot.... @amaitland

Comment: Others have used https://github.com/red-gate/RedGate.AppHost to run CefSharp successfully out of process,  might be worth looking into.

Comment: thanks again.. I see a related example at https://github.com/rupertsciamenna89/cefsharp-remoting I will investigate.. This is a large effort and some rewrite for our current application so will need some time but think this is a way forward.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no easy answer to this problem as word / excel can load only one libcef dll in memory. The redgate apphost could be a possible solution and I added a link to cefsharp remoting repo which I am still trying to make work but has some readymade code and could be a good starting point for someone trying to do the same thing. Best of luck and thanks @amaitland for pointers.